# Why is the command \appendix preferred over \begin{appendices}, ...\end{appendices}?

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

This is a follow-up question to [How to replace the word "Chapter" for appendix items with "Appendix" in book using titlesec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/231872/5764).

I've tried `\begin{appendices}` ... `\end{appendices}` and, whilst it does not show any errors, the word Chapter appears for Appendix items in TOC.

Change to `\appendix` (and do nothing else) and the word Chapter changes to Appendix.
I am just surprised because the former would appear to be a more precise control.

Comment: Which question? You have enough reputation to add comments to their answer(s)? Ok, it's this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231872/how-to-replace-the-word-chapter-for-appendix-items-with-appendix-in-book-usi

Comment: It's not preferred. I've simply replaced `\begin{appendices}...\end{appendices}` (to say all the truth it was `\begin{appendix}...\end{appendix}`) with `\appendix` simply to apply `\g@addto@macro` to `\appendix`. You were not using any feature of that environment.

Comment: I've added the same solution with the `appendices` environment in my answer at your previous question.